# Ktor server - print deployment configuration values

Tags: kotlin, server, netty, ktor

I am trying to print out the default configuration values used by my ktor server application. We want the default values for better understanding the performance of the server. Some of the default config values are

```
  connectionGroupSize
  workerGroupSize
  callGroupSize
  ...
```

We use [`EngineMain`](https://ktor.io/docs/engines.html#EngineMain) to run the server application and the code doesn't expose the [`configuration`](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/2d7a285ab8e5fb288337a6df683fe03eb4770a75/ktor-server/ktor-server-netty/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/netty/NettyApplicationEngine.kt#L113) field in the `NettyApplicationEngine` class.

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/jvmAndNix/src/io/ktor/server/engine/ApplicationEngine.kt) be the default values you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the entire configuration values. It could be default or overriden.

Comment: The best you can do is to get the values from the config in an application module: `environment.config.propertyOrNull("connectionGroupSize")?.getString()`

Comment: That property doesn't exist at all. There is a method `environment.config.toMap()` which you can use to print all the config values.

Comment: Then the only option is to use the `embeddedServer` instead of the `EngineMain`.